# How to separate expression into vectors in R

Tags: regex, r

I have an expression `MAX(51)+MIN(52)-53`. I want to separate this expression into two vectors. Like

```
operands=c("MAX(51)","MIN(52)","53");

operators=c("+","-");
```

I have tried the following: But It returns "MIN(51)" "MAX(52)-23" But I want the output as "MIN(51)" "MAX(52)" "23"

```
arr<-c('\\+','\\-','\\*','\\/');
strsplit("MIN(51)+MAX(52)-23", arr);
```

First vector will be an array of operands and 
second vector will be an array of operators.
How to make it possible in R? Using Regular expression and string functions?
Thanks..

Comment: You could try `v1 <- strsplit(x, '(?<=(\\)|[+-]))(?=([+-]|\\w))', perl=TRUE)[[1]]; indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE); v1[indx]; v1[!indx]` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strsplit` and `regmatches` function to get the operands and operators.

```
> x <- "MAX(51)+MIN(52)-53"
> operands <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[-+*/]"))
> operands
[1] "MAX(51)" "MIN(52)" "53"     
> operators <- unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[-+*/]", x)))
> operators
[1] "+" "-"
```

OR

```
operands <- strsplit(x, '[-+*/]')[[1]]
```

OR

```
> operands <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[^a-zA-Z0-9()]+"))
> operands
[1] "MAX(51)" "MIN(52)" "53"     
> operators <- unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^a-zA-Z0-9()]+", x)))
> operators
[1] "+" "-"
```

Comment: no, it's a simple task. [Accept if this helps.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: You don't need unlist here at all

Comment: without unlisting, a list is stored to the variable instead of vectors.

Comment: sorry i don't know what exactly you're asking.

Comment: `operands <- strsplit(x, '[-+*/]')[[1]]`